# Magento 1.9 get custom attribute value that is a dropdown input type

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I have created a custom attribute (**color_materials**) in Magento admin, which input type is set to dropdown. I'm trying to get this attribute value programatically, and I have the following code.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getSku($_item));
$productOption = $product->getData('color_materials');
```

The output i got is a number, which is stored in *catalog_product_entity_int*. But I want to get it's associated **text**, not a number. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **getAttributeText**

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getSku($_item));
 $productOption = $product->getAttributeText('color_materials');
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you also tell me where to get a full list of Magento functions? it was simply because I didn't know there's a function called getAttributeText().

Comment: @Zhenyu the function is located `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` on line **1381** function getAttributeText

Answer (score 1):

Since your attribute type is dropdown `$product->getData('color_materials');` will return you the value.

Since you need the label you can use

```
$product->getAttributeText("color_materials");
```

Other ways

```
$id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$optionValue = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($id,  'color_materials', Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $optionValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$product->getData('color_materials');
```

OR

```
$product->getColorMaterials();
```

Return the **attribute option Id** , in case of dropdown or multiselect.

For fetching attribute option text you have to write below code

```
$product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```