# Can't get custom attribute for value magento 1.9.4.2

Tags: magento-1.9, category-attribute

I have created a Custom Attribute ( attribute id: custom_attribute ) for the category. It shows up in the backend and able to save the value to it. I just wanted to print the value in the Category **view.phtml** template.

I have tried the following to make this happen. But none of them seems to be working for me.

- Reindexed
- Flushed cache

Functions I have tried to get the value.

- `<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')): ?>
     <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
  <?php else: ?>` **Output: Condition false**
- `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getData('custom_attribute')` 
  **Output: Null**
- `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($_category->getId(), "name", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());` **Output: bool(false)**

I have used [silksoftware](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) to create a custom attribute

Comment: refer this links :- https://scriptbaker.com/get-custom-attribute-value-in-magento/
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165415/magento-1-9-get-custom-attribute-value-that-is-a-dropdown-input-type2>

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but both of the links you gave me is used for product object I wanted to get a category object custom attribute, yet I have still tried those `$_category->getAttributeText('custom_attribute');` output: Null.

Comment: If I have no other options, I will go mad and write SQL query in the phtml to get the value.  Someone please help !